# How to know which Asset size will be loaded by Flutter?

Tags: flutter, assets

I want to dynamically load images from the web for my Flutter App, but I don't want to load big images for devices with a small screen, as those devices also tend to be slow and have slower internet connections.

For Assets pre-loaded into the App, I can save them in folders named `2.0x` and etc. and Flutter will automatically load the correct asset for the device's screen resolution. Is it here a way for me to ask Flutter which asset size will be loaded (and get an answer like `2.0`) for the current device, so I can then load the image with that size from my server?

Answer (score 1):

The [devicePixelRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html) property can be used for your use case.
It returns the the number of device pixels for each logical pixel.

> The value returned by devicePixelRatio is ultimately obtained either from the hardware itself, the device drivers, or a hard-coded value stored in the operating system or firmware.